# Is there a way to create an ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED intent from code

Tags: android, android-intent, tags, nfc, ndef

For an app i'm writing i am wondering if it is possible to create an ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED intent from code. Normally this intent is created by the system when reading an ndef formatted tag. It contains a parcableextra of the type Tag.

The creation of the intent is probably easy but can you also create a Tag from code or is that not supported by the class as i suppose.

The goal is to broadcast a virtual tag with an ndef record to the system that then can be handled by an app that calls on the ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED intent.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a mock tag object instance using reflection. Something like this should work:

```
NdefMessage ndefMsg = ...;

Class tagClass = Tag.class;
Method createMockTagMethod = tagClass.getMethod("createMockTag", byte[].class, int[].class, Bundle[].class);

final int TECH_NFC_A = 1;
final int TECH_NDEF = 6;

final String EXTRA_NDEF_MSG = "ndefmsg";
final String EXTRA_NDEF_MAXLENGTH = "ndefmaxlength";
final String EXTRA_NDEF_CARDSTATE = "ndefcardstate";
final String EXTRA_NDEF_TYPE = "ndeftype";

Bundle ndefBundle = new Bundle();
ndefBundle.putInt(EXTRA_NDEF_MSG, 48); // result for getMaxSize()
ndefBundle.putInt(EXTRA_NDEF_CARDSTATE, 1); // 1: read-only, 2: read/write
ndefBundle.putInt(EXTRA_NDEF_TYPE, 2); // 1: T1T, 2: T2T, 3: T3T, 4: T4T, 101: MF Classic, 102: ICODE
ndefBundle.putParcelable(EXTRA_NDEF_MSG, ndefMsg);

Tag mockTag = (Tag)createMockTagMethod.invoke(null,
        new byte[] { (byte)0x12, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x56, (byte)0x78 },
        new int[] { TECH_NFC_A, TECH_NDEF },
        new Bundle[] { null, ndefBundle });
```

The problem with this is that you will not be able to connect to this tag. Consequently, all methods of the `Ndef` object (that you can get from that mock `Tag` instance) that require IO operations with a real tag or a real tag that is registered with the NFC service will fail. Specifically, only

- `getCachedNdefMessage()`,
- `getMaxSize()`,
- `getType()`,
- `isWritable()`, and
- `getTag()`

will work.

So pretty much the same functionality would be available if you do not pass a `Tag` object as part of the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent and instead just use the `EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES` intent extra.